# Parallel Programming with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, parallel-processing

I want to fill a database table in SQL database with c#. I should find the distinct packet in the database and then for each packet, first I should fill a data table contain all rows for that packet and then find the depth for that row. I am using the following function to speed up the process by using Parallel tasking:

```
private void DoParrallelComputing(DataTable dtpacket, string Identifier)
{
  con = new SqlConnection(strConnect);

  Dictionary<int, DataTable> dtsName = new Dictionary<int, DataTable>();
  Dictionary<int, SqlDataAdapter> ReaderName = new Dictionary<int, SqlDataAdapter>();
  Dictionary<int, string> strName = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  Dictionary<int, SqlCommand> cmdName = new Dictionary<int, SqlCommand>();

  Dictionary<int, int> Node = new Dictionary<int, int>();
  Dictionary<int, string> NodeID = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  Dictionary<int, string> ParentID = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  Dictionary<int, int> Depth = new Dictionary<int, int>();

  Parallel.For(0, dtpacket.Rows.Count - 1, i =>
  {
    progressBarTree.Value = i;

    Application.DoEvents();
    string packetID = dtpacket.Rows[i][0].ToString();

    strName[i] = "";
    strName[i] = "SELECT Node,NodeID,ParentId,Depth from tblTree where [Identifier]='" + Identifier + "' and [PacketId]='" + packetID + "'";
    strName[i] = strName[i] + " order by [Node]";

    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
      con.Open();
    }

    ReaderName[i] = new SqlDataAdapter(strName[i], con);
    dtsName[i] = new DataTable();

    ReaderName[i].Fill(dtsName[i]);

    int rowsCount = 0;
    rowsCount = dtsName[i].Rows.Count - 1;

    for (int j = rowsCount; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      Application.DoEvents();
      Node[i] = Form1.val_int(dtsName[i].Rows[j][0].ToString());
      NodeID[i] = dtsName[i].Rows[j][1].ToString();
      ParentID[i] = dtsName[i].Rows[j][2].ToString();
      Depth[i] = 0;

      for (int ii = j - 1; ii >= 0; ii--)
      {
        string dtParent = "";
        string nodeParent = "";

        dtParent = dtsName[i].Rows[ii][1].ToString();
        nodeParent = ParentID[i];

        if (dtParent == nodeParent)
        {
          ParentID[i] = dtsName[i].Rows[ii][2].ToString();
          Depth[i]++;
        }
      }

      //Update Tree table
      strName[i] = "update tblTree set depth=" + Depth[i] + " where node=" + Node[i].ToString();

      if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
      {
        con.Open();
      }

      cmdName[i] = new SqlCommand(strName[i], con);
      cmdName[i].ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmdName[i].Dispose();
    }
  });
}
```

But when I run this function, I can see that the CPU usage goes to 70% with 4 cores CPU and see also the application uses about 300 Threads but after i.e 10 minutes I can not see any change in the database! If I do not use Parallel Tasks, then it takes about 20 days to finish that is why I want to use Parallel Tasks.

Comment: First observation: You should do as much of this on the database server as possible. If you're using SQL Server, you can use a CTE to calculate the depth of a node within the tree. See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/ Also - it looks like ALL of that can be done on the SQL server, which is optimized for this type of thing. Avoid joining data on the client.

Comment: Passing 300 commands in parallel through a single SqlConnection can't end well..

Comment: Thanks, My structure is like: there are some packets and for each packet I have hierarchical structure, I mean each row occur after its parent in the database, So how can I do that in the database?

Comment: The number of commands are about 2000 copmmands in some cases!!

Answer (score 4):

1. One does not build SQL commands by concatenating values in it like `[Identifier]='" + Identifier + "'`. This is a SQL injection attack vector, you should never write code like this. Use parameters: `[Identifier] = @identifier` and add the parameter value to the command. Before proceeding , do yourself a favor and read [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx).
2. Adding threads ad nauseam does not make code run faster, it will make it run **slower**. If you want to achieve better throughput, you must use asynchronous database commands. MAke sure you decorate the connection string with [`AsyncronouwProcessing = true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) then use [`BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx). Throttle the number of outstanding requests.
3. Using DataAdapater and DataTable is the sure shot way to slow performance. Use raw [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx). I refer you again to Bob Beauchamin's article linked before.
4. Don't do processing on the client, the SQL Server is *much* better at it.
5. Don't do row-by-painfully-slow-row processing, use set oriented logic. Recursive CTEs can be used to do hierarchical processing, see [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx).

There are many more problems with your code (like the presence of a an event loop, clear indication that this code does not belong on an UI thread, the frequent `ToString()` calls clearly indicating the lack of  understanding of the type system, the explicit calls to `Dispose` instead of relying on `using(...)` blocks, the blind re-opening of connections etc etc etc.

Your first and foremost focus should be in addressing the problem by expressing it as a single CTE based UPDATE statement. W/o a complete definition of the data schema and the requirement one can only guess what you're trying to do, but it would be something like this:

```
with cte as (
  select Node, NodeID, ParentId, Depth, 0 as ComputedDepth
  from tblTree 
  where [Identifier]= @Identifier
  union all
  select c.Node, c.NodeID, c.ParentId, c.Depth, p.ComputedDepth+1
  from tblTree c
  join cte p on c.ParentId = p.NodeId)
update cte
  set Depth = ComputedDepth;
```

Here is an actual example:

```
create table tblTree (
[NodeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[Identifier] [varchar](10) NULL, 
[ParentID] [int] NULL, 
[Depth] [tinyint] NULL);
GO

insert into tblTree (Identifier, ParentID) 
    values ('Foo', NULL)
        , (NULL, 1)
        , (NULL, 1)
        , (NULL, 2)
        , (NULL, 4)
        , ('Bar', NULL);
go

declare @identifier VARCHAR(10) = 'Foo';
with cte as (
    select NodeID, 0 as Depth
    from tblTree
    where Identifier = @identifier
    union all
    select c.NodeID, p.Depth+1
    from tblTree c
    join cte p on c.ParentID = p.NodeID)
update t
    set t.Depth = c.Depth
from tblTree t 
join cte c on t.NodeID = c.NodeID;
go

select * from tblTree;
```

Comment: Thanks, my tblTree table structure is as follow: [Node] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Identifier] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [PacketID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [NodeID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 [Depth] [tinyint] NULL ===> How can I calculate depth on this table in SQL?

Comment: Another comment is: the depth calculation should occur for each [PacketID] separately. So I add another constrain like: join cte p on c.ParentId = p.NodeId and c.PacketID = p.PacketID to the expression.

Comment: I execute your suggestion on SQL and get this error: Derived table 'cte' is not updatable because a column of the derived table is derived or constant.

Comment: I can not run the above CTE because I got this error: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 32767 has been exhausted before statement completion." Any suggestion?

Comment: It means your data has cycles (node A is parent of node B and node B is parent of node A). Fix your data.

Comment: I change my function, now I use 5 parallel tasks with some temporary table and it works :) Thank you for your advices.

Comment: @Ramus:You know, the problem is that my data can have cycles because I am working on communication. So i.e. A can be parent of B and in 1 or 2 lower level B can be parent of A! So I can not use CTE and I write my custom CTE with c#. Anyway, thank you so much for your help which enable me to understand lots of problem with my codes.